# Docker not seeing mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803, even though it is installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

On windows 10 Enterprise. Docker version 2.3.0.4 community. Using visual studio 2019. Simple asp.net core project with docker support.It builds ok. Using windows container.  Then running in Docker, I get:

> The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not
> found.

In the Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803 AS base
```

On the PC I have in the folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, a folder '3.1.0' with this version of the framework.

In Powershell, I have tried pulling the framework, with the following result.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803
3.1-nanoserver-1803: Pulling from dotnet/core/aspnet
Digest: sha256:3b4383b72b53a00895267571d08e9591eab1b914f35b2c2c4a2413d178eca089
Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803
```

So I really don't understand why docker can't find it.

Comment: We need a [mcve] here. Show your entire dockerfile and what your doing to run it, etc.

Comment: Docker file:FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8082
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SharesD.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./SharesD.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "SharesD.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SharesD.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SharesD.dll"]

Comment: I am running the dockerfile by sending it to docker from visual studio using the 'Docker' button in the GUI. I then see the image running in the Docker dashboard.

Comment: Here is the full output from the dashboard: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.

- The following frameworks were found:

3.1.0-preview3.19555.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]


You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.


The specified framework can be found at:

- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

Comment: Please edit the question. You should avoid adding details in comments

Comment: I have managed to get rid of this error by compiling the release version in Visual Studio. Before I was only compiling the debug version.  I do not see why I need to do this as the Dockerfile instructs the docker system to compile the release version.  ('run dotnet build 'xxx' -c Release'). Doesn't make any sense to me.  I did not make any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has stopped the support for nanoserver, this will end in nov. And there is no image with tag mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803 even though VS2019adds this by default for windows containers.
Better switch to linux and proceed

reference:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1469

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1698